# Implement quad-tree as B-tree?

Tags: spatial-database, spatial-index

I've heard that quadtrees (as used in spatial-indexing) can be implemented on top of the B-tree structure for non-spatial indexes.

For example, [comments in a blog](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/11/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Spatial-indexing-with-Quadtrees-and-Hilbert-Curves) says:

> with R-trees you are building a disk-based, ideally transactional data
>   structure from scratch, which is a big undertaking. With z order and
>   Hilbert order, you just use any convenient b-tree

But I couldn't find details about how to implement a quad-tree as a B-tree.

Can anyone explain the main ideas here?

Answer (score 2):

When encoding a two-dimensional quadtree cell in [z-order (or Morton order)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve), you assign each quadtree node a code that contains interlaced horizontal and vertical indices of the quadtree node. For example, the cell `(7,4)`, is `("111", "100")` in binary, and interlacing those two numbers gives `"111010"`, which is your z-order code for the same cell.

You can insert such codes into a B-tree in the same way as you would use the two-dimensional cell indices in a quadtree.

The z-order representation makes the quadtree hierarchy easily visible even in coded format. To get the code for the parent quadtree node, just remove the last two bits from the code - parent of `(7, 3)` from before is `"1110"`, which corresponds to quadtree cell `(3, 2)`.

In case you want storage and performance efficiency, you might want to use integers for your z-order codes (`"111010"` becomes `58`). However, if you need to store information against more than one level of the quadtree, you'll have to account for the different lengths of the codes at different levels, e.g. by prefixing the binary code with a `"1"` bit (`"1"+"111010"` becomes `122`).